# Is there any open technology for encryption all the code like an encrypt container?

Tags: encryption, code

Is there any open technology for encryption all the code ?

[image]

You see the black frame, I want there is a technology like it to avoid source code come to light.

Comment: But that's how all webapps already work? You cannot get a PHP app's source code via port 80.

Comment: If someone can access your server, you've already lost.

Comment: I mean use the black frame to encrypt code, so if in the server there cannot see the source code.

Comment: Let me repeat: once someone has access to your server, you've already lost. Stop attackers from accessing the server, not from reading the code once they've done that. Web apps are more than just code.